# How to let visio shapes change behaviour from their text?

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I have shapes that should change behaviour on the basis of their text.

Text fields change their height and with using `=GUARD(TEXTWIDTH(TheText))` just fine.

But when I try to let something change color like this `=THEMEGUARD(IF(LEN(TheText)>3,RGB(255,112,192),RGB(0,112,192)))` nothing happens when you change the text.

Any ideas on how to get visio to actually run this like it should? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or am I doing something wrong here?

Please try add [SHAPETEXT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/shapetext-function).

With syntax like       `=THEMEGUARD(IF(LEN(SHAPETEXT(TheText))>3,RGB(255,112,192),RGB(0,112,192)))`

> [image: Test of this formula result]

I check this formula at my side, it works!